# Finding a contradiction for analysis problem

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, divisibility

> Let $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be a non-decreasing function such that $f(n) \vert n$ is true for only finitely many $n$. Show that there exists a constant $c > 0$ such that $f(n)>cn$ for all $n.$

So trying to find a contradiction one would want to show that $\frac{n}{f(n)} = k$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ holds for infinitely many $n$.

From here one can let $g(n) = n - kf(n).$ The problem now becomes to find if $g(n)$ can equal $0$.

My question is that can I use continuity here in order to show this since the problem statement doesn't tell anything about if $f(n)$ is continuous?

One could argue that $g(1) = 1-kf(1) \leqslant 1-k \leqslant 0$ and if one would choose $c=\frac1k$ that would imply that $f(n) > \frac1k n$.

This would result in $g(n) = n-kf(n) > n-k \frac{n}{k} = n-n = 0$

and from Bolzano's theorem the result would follow.

Answer (score 1):

Continuity doesn't really mean much for a function on a discrete set.

We can use induction.

Special case:  Suppose that $f(n)$ never divides $n$.  Then we contend that $f(n)>n$ for all $n$.

Pf:  By induction.  Indeed, $f(1)>1$.  Suppose that we have shown that $f(i)>i$ for all $i<n$.  Then, in particular, $f(n-1)>n-1$. Since $f(n)≥f(n-1)$ we must have $f(n)≥n$.  If we had equality then $f(n)=n$ would divide $n$, contrary to the assumption on $f$, and we are done.

General case:  Since there are only finitely many $n$ for which $f(n)\,|\,n$, we let $K$ be the greatest integer for which $f(K)\,|\,K$.  Then $F(n)=(K+1)f(n)$ can never divide $n$, so we can apply the special case to $F(n)$.  It follows that $$(K+1)f(n)>n\implies f(n)>\frac 1{K+1}n$$ and we are done.

Comment: Is this argument correct for your $F(n)$? . If $n\le K$ , then $F(n) | n$ is not possible since $(K+1)f(n) \ge (K+1) \gt n$, a contradiction since $F(n) \le n$ must hold.   And if $ n \ge (K+1)$ , then $(K+1)f(n) | n$ implies $f(n) |n$ which contradicts maximality of $K$

Comment: @user710290  Yes, that's fine.

Comment: Ok Thank you +1from me

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could elaborate on what do you mean by "Continuity doesn't really mean much for a function on a discrete set"? Also by discrete set do you mean that a point doesn't contain any other points in its neighborhood?

Comment: Well, what topology did you have in  mind for $\mathbb N$?  If you take the one induced by being a subset of $\mathbb R$, then every natural number is open, so every function from $\mathbb N$ is continuous.

Comment: Indeed $\mathbb{N}$ would be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. If that's the case wouldn't my original argument hold as well?

Comment: Bolzano only applies to connected sets.  It's easy to come up with functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb Z$ that change signs but which never vanish.

Comment: I should say:  I don't understand your argument at all.  I don't see where you are using the assumptions, for instance.